# Problem Installing azure-pipeline due to ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-machine-learning-service, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to install azure-pipeline using:

```
pip install azureml-pipeline
```

When I do this it installs most dependencies fine until I receive the following error messages:

```
Building wheel for ruamel.yaml (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
```

- 

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for ruamel.yaml
```

- 

```
Running setup.py install for ruamel.yaml did not run successfully.
```

Note that when I install ruamel.yaml with pip it says all requirements are satisfied and when I try to reinstall the wheel tool all requirements are satisfied:

```
pip install ruamel.yaml
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
```

Has anyone encountered this problem or know something I need to install maybe to get this to work? Note: Azureml is installed on my machine fine.

Edit:

Python Version = 3.9.7

OS = macOS Monterey v12.3.1

Here is a link to the error message in full: https://github.com/bencouser/errormessages/blob/main/error.txt

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your environment tries to create a wheel. The documented way to install `ruamel.yaml` is to do:

```
pip install ruamel.yaml
```

that will get you the wheel if it is available.

You should try to run the command above before running `pip install azureml-pipeline` and see if that solves the proglem. If that doesn't work, provide more information ((link to) full error trace, python version, host platform/architecture).

Comment: Hi, how would I go about linking to the error trace? I'm new to asking questions on here sorry. Thanks for the time and suggestion but I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: upload it to some server, or just paste in the whole message, it will show in a scrollbox. Is this on an Mac with M1 processor?

Comment: No I have the intel i5, thanks

Comment: I have also added the error message onto my github

Comment: the important line is `ruamel.yaml<=0.15.89,>=0.15.35`, someone pinned this on an old version released Feb 2019 that included the C loader (now a seperate package). Python 3.9.0 was released October 2020, so that will not have the right headers. Use Python 3.7 and file a bug report with azureml-pipeline. I would also recommend not using anaconda, but a normal Python install and making virtualenvs in which you install azureml-pipeline

Comment: Thanks both, I will do the bug report as soon as